# How to setup a grunt file to watch and compile less files

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I'm trying to use grunt to compile my less files into css while in development. While at it also, watch and reload. The file I've wrote is this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
    less: {
        development: {
            options: {
                compress: true,
                yuicompress: true,
                optimization: 2
            },
            files: {
                // target.css file: source.less file
                "public/css/bootstrap.css": "./public/less/bootstrap.less"
            }
        }
    },
    watch: {
        styles: {
            // Which files to watch (all .less files recursively in the less directory)
            files: ["public/less/*"],
            tasks: ['less'],
            options: {
                livereload: true,
            }
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
};
```

And I have this saved as a gruntfile.js in my project root's directory. What am I doing wrong?

PS: I'm using forever to start my app and in the same terminal window I'm using the command grunt watch, however when I change my less files nothing happens.

PPS: My file structure is as follows:

```
root
  -- public
    -- less
    -- css
```

As you can see above my main less file is located at root/public/less/bootstrap.less and I'd like the css to be compiled at root/public/css/bootstrap.css

Many thanks

Comment: Hi Bogdan. A couple of things: my file doesn't have the line which was causing the problem in the aforementioned question and secondly, the above code is not even compiling the css. To make it clear, nothing happens. Neither my less is being compiled nor the browser is reloaded.

Comment: Try with `grunt --verbose`. It should list the files it is watching and give more information as to what the problem could be. I can't see the issue in your config.

Comment: For future reference, when I tried with --verbose I could see that grunt was working, however it was not watching less files in the public/less directory and its children. The file I was editing was located in public/less/something/myfile.less therefore Grunt changing it was not triggering any action. Once I realised that I've changed the config to public/less/*/* which ten worked.

Comment: @WagnerMatosUK you can also post your own answer as you resolved it and mark it as right. It will help the users coming in future with same problem to find the solution quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup seems to be good but I found a problem here... may be it solves your Question

```
"public/css/bootstrap.css": "./public/less/bootstrap.less"
                             ^^
```

your url is same but in second appearance you have add extra "./" I think if you remove this it will work.

This is my own code and it is working fine.

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
    grunt.initConfig({
        //pkg:grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        less:{
              development:{
                  options:{
                      compress: true,
                      yuicompress: true,
                      optimization: 2
                  },
                files:{
                    'webroot/css/meer/index/index2.css' : 'webroot/css/meer/index/index2.less'
                }
              }
        },
        watch: {
            styles:{
                options:{
                    livereload: true,
                    spawn: false,
                    event: ['added','deleted','changed']
                },
                files:['webroot/css/meer/index/*.less'],
                tasks:['less']
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.registerTask('default',['watch']);
}
```